# Using varying labels in Userform code

Tags: vb.net

I have a simulator with two userforms that transfer information back and forth between each other (one is MainForm, and the other is CreatureFinder).

When one of the deck slot buttons on MainForm is pushed (all 20 of which correspond to a creature in either your or the enemy's deck), it opens CreatureFinder so that you can choose which creature goes in the slot (and it also lets you edit certain parameters, like the creature's level).

The code shortened for simplicity:

```
If CreatureNumberLabel.Text = "1" Then
   MainForm.YourCreature1Skill1Label.Text = Skill1Label.Text
   MainForm.YourCreature1Skill2Label.Text = Skill2Label.Text
   MainForm.YourCreature1Skill3Label.Text = Skill3Label.Text
End If
```

I want to remove the If Then statement, and to change "YourCreature1" to "YourCreature" & whatever value CreatureNumberLabel.Text is set to.

Comment: You can use `DirectCast(Me.Controls("name"), Label.Text = "your text"` and just replace _name_ with the name of the control you want to get. As it's a normal string it can be concatenated with numbers from a loop for example.

Comment: are you using VBA or VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be VBA, you can skip the

```
If CreatureNumberLabel.Text = "1" Then
```

And just type:

```
MainForm.Controls("YourCreature" & CreatureNumberLabel.Text & "Skill1Label").Text = Skill1Label.Text
```

And so on with `Skill2Label.Text`, `Skill3Label.Text`, etc...

Comment: This applies to VB.NET. Not sure if VBA, maybe both?

Comment: This worked great! I actually had something close to this, but didn't know that I had to put the "Controls" part, so I kept getting an error XD

Comment: @VisualVincent: it does work in VBA like I wrote. Only in VBA you'd use the Label "Capiton" property instead of the "Text" one. But I just copied/pasted and adapted OP'S snippet...

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of control arrays. On form load, create array(s) for controls and assign its elements (this is 20 lines of code per array), afterwards you can use them like next:

```
Dim CreatureNum As Integer = CInt(CreatureNumberLabel.Text)  'don't forget validation
MainFormYourCreatureSkillLabelArray(CreatureNum).Text = SkillLabel(CreatureNum).Text
```